# Increase RAM available for Knime?

Tags: knime

Is there an easy way to increase the RAM available in Knime through a config file or through menu options?

I am constantly running into "heap-space" errors during execution and it by default limits the number of categorical variables to 1,000, as well as difficulty displaying charts with more than n values (~10,000).

Example error:

```
ERROR Decision Tree Learner 0:65       Execute failed: Java heap space
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can edit `knime.ini` (in the `knime` or `knime_<version>` folder) and change the row starting with `-Xmx` (I think by default it is `2048m`, two GiB). Though do not use so much memory that would cause the OS to swap as Java do not play very well with swapping.

(Displaying too many variables might still be slow, maybe you could aggregate them somehow.)

Comment: Thanks!!! It took me forever to find "knime_<version>" because you have to go to a place called "Applications" :) appreciate it - my default was 1 GiB, bumped it up!

Comment: what numbers are allowed?

Comment: @PV8 I think it needs to be at least 1m (though that would probably start with OutOfMemoryError). The max is probably better be around the free RAM available (but less ~100m), swapping can be counter-productive, so more is not a good choice.

Comment: it has to be divided by 8?

Comment: In case you mean bits, than yes, these numbers mean bytes (`m` means 1024*1024 bytes, `g` means 1024*1024*1024 bytes).